# How to add table column data to another similar column table in mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have two similar tables in different database and those tables have similar columns. Suppose i have Db name `image1` and table name `tbl_image` with columns `id`,`f_name`,`l_name` and that table have more than 50 > data

also i have another Db name `image2` and table name `tbl_image` also that have column `id`,`f_name`,`l_name` and that table also have more than 50 > data

How can i add `image2` database table data to `image1` database table.can any one give me idea for this.

Comment: Use `join` and when using add database name in front of the table **ex:** `image1.tbl_image` and `image2.tbl_image`

Comment: the two databases are on the same mysql server ????

Comment: add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: yes,that all are in same database

Comment: What you are going to do  Insert or update or delete?

Comment: i need to insert in one table to other .

Comment: Okay, So what data to be inserted? If you can share some sample data and result set it would be much easier to answer rather than asking one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two tables have the same structure (meaning they also share the same type for each column), to merge the two tables you can simply use

```
INSERT INTO image1.tbl_image SELECT * FROM image2.tbl_image
```

This assumes your `id` in the two tables do not overlap.

If you have duplicates, but you are not bound to those values (you don't mention foreign keys), you can insert the data from `image2.tbl_image` like this

```
INSERT INTO image1.tbl_image SELECT NULL,f_name,l_name FROM image2.tbl_image
```

which will give all rows from `image2.tbl_image` a new `id`.

Comment: that both have id is primary key

Comment: Every table should have one, but what I do here is inserting the data from the second table into the first one. If every row in the second table has `id` different from any row in the first table, you can simply insert the values from `image2` to `image1`.